# Unexpected behaviour of array.count in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi i am using Rails3 when i puts array of subscribers like this

```
    @subscribers = User.all
```

and puts it.gives me this array

```
     [#<User id: 62, is_activated: true, subscriber: "TEST_DB2", ports_order: 100, created_at: "2012-05-21 14:47:48">, #<User id: 66, is_activated: true, subscriber: "JOHI", ports_order: 100, created_at: "2012-05-22 12:06:19">, #<User id: 68, is_activated: true, subscriber: "ALI-NAQWI", ports_order: 100, created_at: "2012-05-24 11:01:22">]
```

And when i give command 
                    @subscribers.count         #it give me 0 count

Why?????????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try length instead, it can be a bug in AREL :)

That he is trying to lazy do something. He is giving back proxy object so it can be a problem there. Length will always work on your result value ~ array.